# Why reusable workflow step fails from a different repo but succeeds from same repo?

Tags: github, github-actions, openid-connect, azure-cli

I am using GitHub Actions for CI/CD. I have a reusable workflow added in a repo named BuildTemplate so that future projects can use this template. The reusable workflow has a simple step to log in to Azure and subsequently download a file from key vault. The secrets for Azure login are all kept under BuildTemplate repo's settings -> secrets and variables -> actions -> repository secrets.

```yaml
  jobs:
    download_secure_file:
     runs-on: [self-hosted, github-my-selfhosted-runner]
     steps:
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: Azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
```

When this reusable workflow step is being called from a different repo, like this:

```yaml
    jobs:
      download_secure_file:
        name: Download Secure File
        uses: MyOrg/MyReusableRepo/.github/workflows/template-download-secure-file.yml@main
```

the step fails with the below error:

```
Run Azure/login@v1
Error: Az CLI Login failed. Please check the credentials and make sure az is installed on the runner. For more information refer https://aka.ms/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows
```

When this login step is in a reusable workflow which is in the same repo, it works:

```
Run Azure/login@v1
Using OIDC authentication...
Federated token details: 
 issuer - https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com 
 subject claim - repo:MyOrg/MyRepo:ref:refs/heads/feature/MyFeature-7596
/usr/bin/az cloud set -n azurecloud
Done setting cloud: "azurecloud"
Login successful.
```

Why does the login fail when the reusable workflow is called from a different repo? I went through GitHub Actions documentation and did not see anything that I am missing here such that the reusable workflow fails. Please note even though the error shows "make sure az is installed on the runner", it is not needed as it is the same runner machine where this step succeeds without having the need to install Azure CLI.

What is the actual issue here?

Comment: The secrets have to come from the caller workflow: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - which means I need to define the same secret in each repository that is going to call this reusable workflow. And also include the details described in the link to each of the calling workflow? If that is the case, is there anything I can do to avoid these repeated tasks - ie; secret is kept only in the reusable template's repo and not in the calling repos. And also avoid any duplicate yml code being added to the called workflows.

Comment: You can't keep the secret in the reusable template repo, but it could be [org-level](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-an-organization) and then exposed to the repos that need it. You could also look into [environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment).

Comment: OK - I have to raise a ticket with the admin to add the secrets at org level. But can I ask if I do this, then calling workflow(no secret) -> called workflow(secret accessed from org). Will this possibly resolve the issue I face?

Comment: I can't tell you it will work perfectly, but it should at least be able to access the credentials then. Maybe start small - rather than trying to fix it for everyone, add the secrets to your calling repo. Once everything's working (assuming you get it all working) _then_ you can raise them to the org level so others can reuse it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I have added the secrets to my calling repo and tried this, ref: the success case in my post above

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there... All you have to do is pass secrets from the calling workflow otherwise secrets are null hence your job is getting failed.

```
jobs:
  download_secure_file:
    name: Download Secure File
    uses: MyOrg/MyReusableRepo/.github/workflows/template-download-secure-file.yml@main
    secrets: inherit
```

while specifying secrets: inherit , you can solve the issue.

Comment: - Thanks for your response. I have tried this before and know the problem here is then I have to define the same set of secrets in each individual repo which is going to use the reusable workflow

Comment: instead of passing secrets while calling reusable workflow, you can simply use secrets: inherit.
defining secrets and passing them while calling on each repo is hectic work:-)

Comment: I have defined now secrets at the organisation level. In order that the parent passes this organisation level secret to the called workflow what need to be done?